# $P(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$. There exist $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\underbrace{P(P(\ldots P(y)\ldots))}_{n}=y$. Prove $P(P(y))=y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $P(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$. There exist $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$\underbrace{P(P(\ldots P(y)\ldots))}_{n}=y$$
>
> Prove $P(P(y))=y$.

I think the notation $P^n(y)=y$ is also standard somewhere. If $n\in\{1,2\}$, then it's trivial. I don't know the exact source of the problem. It could be an olympiad problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If $P(P(y))=y$ then is it valid that $P(y)\in \Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: @LivaditisAlex $P(y)\in\mathbb Z$. We have that $y$ is a fixed given integer.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood and thought that we are talking for polynomials.

Comment: @JeanMarie I disagree with your edit. My title lets you find what the problem is really about in the "Related" section on the right or if you're writing a new question in the list of possibly duplicate questions. And the description of the problem I wrote is shorter than what you suggest and still clear, grammatically correct.

Comment: This is indeed an Olympiad problem. You can find the solution here (Problem 5) : http://www.georgmohr.dk/imo/imo06pbsol.pdf
(The answer to your question is the first part of the solution of the problem.)

Comment: @Vincent Its not just about the seconds at the end. Plus I hope for a better solution.

Comment: You are free, but it wasn't an issue of grammatical correctness. I was trying to apply a general rule for titles that they shouldn't contain formulas.

Comment: @JeanMarie If you see the "Related" section on the right, or just any new questions, you'll find plenty of LaTeX in titles. It lets you see the exact problem instead of a vague description. Otherwise you'd have to click a lot to find duplicates or any precise problems you're searching for.

Comment: @Alephnull I don't understand the meaning of your remark to Vincent

Comment: @user263326 it is not because in SE you find many titles like that it is a good habit. As researcher, I guarantee you that is it completely exceptional that a research article has a formula in its title. I say a formula with $\cdots = \cdots$ ; it happens or course that you have (latex) mathematical set notations, for example such as $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. This is well admitted.

Comment: Can you use induction? If it's true for $n$ then  $P^{n+2}(y) = P^n(P(P(y))) = P^n(y)$ so it's true for $n  + 2$ (with the same $y$)

Comment: In what (maximal) sense can we say a (particular) integer-coefficient polynomial is similar to  some rational-coefficient polynomial? I believe their graphs are pairwise similar in the geometric sense. This sense i believe is sufficient.

Comment: @fleablood I don't think you are capturing the logical complexity of the problem. When you increase n you are modifying the class of potential polynomials (if you are not begging the ?) While it is not explicitly phrased as such, this is a conditional.

Comment: Yeah but they are asking to prove there exists a single instance. We don't need to worry about potential polynomials when we have a y that does.  Is That there always exist a $n, y$ such that is true just a given or are we to prove it.  I took the question to be to prove there exists a y where it is true.  Not to prove it was for all y where P^n(y) = y.

Comment: @fleablood That's not the question. The $y,n$ are given with the condition $P^n(y)=y$ and you have to prove that $P(P(y))=y$.

Comment: Okay, I found the question ambiguous.  I'm still wondering if induction is possible.  If P^{n+2}(y) = y then P^n(P(P(y))= y and P(P(P^n(y))) =y.  I don't see how to do it but I wonder if we can somehow.

Comment: @fleablood It would make sense to try to induce on the degree of P. This determines the curvaceousness of the graph which is important. If P is strictly increasing for instance so is the se uence of compositions.

Comment: Suppose we showed it for all k<= n.  spose $P^{n+1}(x) = x$ and $P^{n-1}(x) = z$ then $P^{n+1}(x) = P^2(z) = x$.  $P^{n-1}(P^2(z)) = P^{n+1}(x) = x = P^2(z)$.  So P(P(z)) = z.  But x = P(P(z)) = z = P(P(x)).  Hence... shown by induction.

Answer (score 3):

In view of comments: Extracting from Olympiad (it was also shown some time ago by W. Narkiewics and possibly before...?). There are various generalizations to other rings and certain algebraic number fields. That tends to be very complicated. The integer case is easy and neat:

Let $y_0=y$ be an integer of period $p$ and not a fixed point. Set inductively $y_{k+1}=P(y_k)$ so that $y_p=y_0$. The trick is to look at succesive differences (all non-zero):

$$ y_{k+2}-y_{k+1}= P(y_{k+1}) - P(y_k)= R_k (y_{k+1}-y_k) .$$
By factorization, simply use that $y_{k+1}^n-y_k^n=(y_{k+1}-y_k)(y_{k+1}^{n-1} + \cdots y_k^{n-1})$, we see that $R_k$ must be an integer. Then by recursion (and using $y_p=y_0$):
$$ y_1-y_0= y_{p+1}-y_p=R_{p-1} ... R_0 (y_1-y_0)$$
shows that each $R_k=\pm 1$. If $R_j=-1$ then $y_{j+2}-y_{j+1} = y_j - y_{j+1}$ so $y_{j+2}=y_j$ and we have a 2-cycle. If every $R_j=1$ then every increment is the same and $0=y_0-y_0=y_p - y_0 = p (y_1-y_0)$. Impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If

$$P^n(y)=y$$

Then it should be clear that

$$y=P^n(y)=P^{2n}(y)=\dots$$

And we may take the following limit:

$$y=\lim_{a\to\infty}P^{an}(y)$$

And if the limit exists, it is simple that

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}P^{an}(y)=\lim_{a\to\infty}P^{an+b}(y)$$

For any $b\in\mathbb Z$

And that actually implies

$$y=P^2(y)$$

for $b=1,2$